# python printing 2 text files horizontally next to each other

Tags: python, command-prompt, photo, display, horizontal-line

I have made multiple text files that I want to join together to make a map[image]

what I want is textfile1 to be next to textfile2,

but instead it dose textfile1 then textfile2 on the next line since

[image]

the files are multiple lines.

[image]

so far the best output has been achieved from using
~lines = [Map1.splitlines(), Map2.splitlines()]
for l in zip(*lines):
print(*l, sep="")~

but still isn't perfect

[image]

Comment: can you show your code so we can know what you have done.

Comment: You may need to print contents from both files on the same line. Assume you are reading the contents from each of the file into lists. Then you can iterate through them one by one and print the contents from the 3 files in a single line.

Comment: With the first file, create a string array. With each additional file, append to each string element. After all files are loaded, print each string in the array.

Comment: I am aware that I can get it to print the top line then the line below and so on, but I'm really hoping to avoid that if possible. Is there any way I can make the entire thing text and print together rather than it be coded in as different lines, so it's like an image and I can but them next to each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    lines = [Map1.splitlines(), Map2.splitlines(), Map3.splitlines(), Map4.splitlines(), Map5.splitlines(), Map6.splitlines()]
    for l in zip(*lines):
        print(*l, sep="")
    lines = [Map7.splitlines(), Map8.splitlines(), Map9.splitlines(), Map10.splitlines(), Map11.splitlines(), Map12.splitlines()]
    for l in zip(*lines):
        print(*l, sep="")
    lines = [Map13.splitlines(), Map14.splitlines(), Map15.splitlines(), Map16.splitlines(), Map17.splitlines(), Map18.splitlines()]
    for l in zip(*lines):
        print(*l, sep="")
    lines = [Map19.splitlines(), Map20.splitlines(), Map21.splitlines(), Map22.splitlines(), Map23.splitlines(), Map24.splitlines()]
    for l in zip(*lines):
        print(*l, sep="")
```

Answer (score 0):

using  ~lines = [Map1.splitlines(), Map2.splitlines()] for l in zip(*lines): print(*l, sep="")~
i have edited the text documents to display normally and it works, just annoying to redo the files.